# Not able to show data labels of column in highchart , incorrect format is showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to show datetime format on the top of the column, when I tried to show column labels its showing incorrect result, not formatted proper. I'm getting proper data in the tool tip(hovering) but not in the labels.

> getting op - 86340000
>
> Expected op - 23:59

code:

```
$('#container3').highcharts({
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    chart: {
                        type: 'column'
                    },
                    xAxis:{
                        type: 'datetime',
                        tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 * 1,
                          dateTimeLabelFormats: { //force all formats to be hour:minute:second
                            day: '%e-%m-%Y',
                        }
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Report'
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        type: 'datetime',
                        dateTimeLabelFormats: { //force all formats to be hour:minute:second
                            second: '%H:%M',
                            minute: '%H:%M',
                            hour: '%H:%M',
                            day: '%H:%M',
                            week: '%H:%M',
                            month: '%H:%M',
                            year: '%H:%M'
                        }
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
         column: {
             dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            y: -20,
            verticalAlign: 'top'
        }
     }
     },
                    tooltip: {
                        pointFormat: "<span style='color:{point.color}'>\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.label}</b><br/>"
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: 'On Duration',
                        data: OnData
                    }, {
                        name: 'Off Duration',
                        data: OffData
                    }]
                });
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Could you reproduce your case with sample data on the online editor which I could work on? Here is my attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f6egyrub/ but I am not sure how your data looks like. I am almost sure that you will be able to set it by using the formatter callback: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.dataLabels.formatter

Comment: i just need the y axis values on the top of the column ,that also im not getting, as it is i want on the top . but dotn know the properties in the plotoptions. i want  type: 'datetime', on the top of culomn

Answer (score 0):

i got required data, when i used the format option , data is formatted as required

```
 plotOptions: {
                        column: {
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                y: -20,
                                verticalAlign: 'top',
                                format: '{point.label}'
                            }
                        }
                    },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
series: [{
    name: 'On Duration',
    data: OnData,
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      rotation: 0,
      color: '#fff',
      align: 'center',
      formatter: function () {
        return new Date(this.y).toISOString().substr(11, 8);
      },
      y: 20,
      style: {
        fontSize: '10px',
        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
        textDecoration : '1px black'
      }
    }   
       
}, {
    name: 'Off Duration',
    data: OffData,
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      rotation: 0,
      color: '#fff',
      align: 'center',
      formatter: function () {
        return new Date(this.y).toISOString().substr(11, 8);
      },
      y: 20,
      style: {
        fontSize: '10px',
        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
        textDecoration : '1px black'
      }
    }   
}]
```